# How to use onclick in amp page

Tags: onclick, amp-html

I'm trying to convert my current page to an AMP page but I'm having some trouble with onclick attributes.

Is there anyway to add that functionality in AMP page?

Below is the tag I want to convert;

```
<img src="theSrc"
     alt=""
     onclick="window.open('link', 'Popup','toolbar=no, location=no, statusbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=1, resizable=0, width=580, height=600, top=30')"
     style="cursor:pointer"
     id="someID"
/>
```

Comment: I accidentally wrote on="click:".. It should be 'tap' instead of 'click'. I have edited the same in the answer. Sorry for any confusion caused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems that you want to show Image, Link and Popup

```
<img src="theSrc"
     alt=""
     onclick="window.open('link', 'Popup','toolbar=no, location=no, statusbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=1, resizable=0, width=580, height=600, top=30')"
     style="cursor:pointer"
     id="someID"
/>
```

You can achieve your goal by combination of `amp-img`, `amp-lightbox` and `amp-iframe`

[Here is the working Url](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vzyVLo)

Code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html amp>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link rel="canonical" href="popup.html">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
   <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
   <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
   <script async custom-element="amp-lightbox" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-lightbox-0.1.js"></script>
   <script async custom-element="amp-iframe" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-iframe-0.1.js"></script>
     <style amp-custom>
    .lightbox {
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
      width: 580px;
      height: 600px;
      margin:30px auto;
      padding:30px;
      position:relative;
    }
    .close { position:absolute; right:5px; top:5px; color: red;    font-family: arial;    font-size: 25px;} 

  </style>

 </head>
 <body>


  <amp-lightbox id="Popup" layout="nodisplay">
    <div class="lightbox" >
      <span class="close" on="tap:Popup.close" role="button" tabindex="0">X</span>
      <amp-iframe width="580" title="Animated dancing GIF from Giphy"
                          height="600"
                          layout="responsive"
                          sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups"
                          frameborder="0"
                          src="https://giphy.com/embed/DKG1OhBUmxL4Q">
    <amp-img layout="fill"
    src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/536538454_640.webp"
    placeholder></amp-img>
    </amp-iframe>
    </div>
  </amp-lightbox>
  <span class="ampstart-btn caps m2" on="tap:Popup" role="button" tabindex="0">
    <amp-img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x50/ff0000/ffffff&text=Click+Here+Image" width="200" height="50" layout="fixed"></amp-img>
  </span>


 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

AMP allows an attribute 'on' inside which you can define various actions corresponding to supported events(see [AMP Actions and Events](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/interaction_dynamic/amp-actions-and-events#element-specific-events)). So your code should be something like:

```
<amp-img src=" "
     alt=""
     role=""
     tabindex=""
     on="tap: <your action here>"
     style=" "
     id=" "
>
<!-- 'role' and 'tabindex' attributes are mandatory when using 'on' attribute
      in some html elements like Bachcha Singh pointed out in the comments.
      Otherwise you will get AMP-validation errors  -->
```

Do note that in AMP we need to use `<amp-img> </amp-img>` tags instead of `<img />` tags. Also I believe you can't use window.open() since only few white listed javascript functions are allowed in AMP, although your desired functionality may be recreated using AMP logic.

Comment: @Chrisabyantoy on="tap:target" does not work with image tag

Comment: @BachchaSingh eh..Please do test it out and confirm. I am pretty sure that it does work. I have personally used it in projects.

Comment: @Chrisabyantoy I mean to say that the way you have written does not work, Its require role and tabindex also.

Comment: @BachchaSingh Okay, that is correct, thanks for pointing out will add that as well.  Your first comment is misleading.